# Constructor(actual and formal arguments differ in length)

Tags: c#, constructor

I get an error when I create an instance from `Dcoder` class:

> Constructor in class cannot be applied to given types.

What is the problem and how my I solve it. This is my class and how I use it in the `Main` method.

```
class Dcoder 
{ 
   int id;
   String name;
   Dcoder(int i, String n) 
   { 
        id=i;
        name=n; 
   } 
}

public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
      Dcoder d1=new Dcoder(786+"Narri");
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code the help us understand how the constructor of the Dcoder class looks like?

Comment: class Dcoder
 { 
  int id;
  String name;
  Dcoder(int i, String n)
  {
   id=i;
   name=n;
   }
   void display()
   
   {
    System.out.println(id+" "+name);
   }

  
 public static void main(String args[])
  { 
   Dcoder d1=new Dcoder(786+"Narri");
   Dcoder d2=new Dcoder(143+"Vellanki");
   d1.display();
   d2.display();
  
  }
 }

Comment: please add your code to the question using [edit] and be sure to format it correctly. Code can be inserted between code tags by highlighting the formatted code and pressing Ctrl + K.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're calling your constructor not in a correct way.
`Dcoder(786,"Narri")` is the correct way for calling your constructor.

Constructor may understand the way you used like it should concatenate the two argument as string: `"786Narri"`. But your class only have one `ctor` takes 2 argument `(int, string)`

Comment: @user10796675 no worries. we'll be happy if you sign the answer as correct one ;)